# Duplicate Record Issue

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to update the record. But due to some reasons I am always getting duplicate record validation.

**Here is my code**

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'Category' => 'required|unique:tblcategory|max:100|min:5'
    ]);

    if ($v->fails()) {
        return redirect('Category/'.$request->input('CategoryID'))
                    ->withErrors($v)
                    ->withInput();
    }
}
```

**Am I missing something ?**

Comment: Probably because your getting a duplicate record, after the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On update you must add the entity ID to avoid finding the same entity when validating the uniqueness:

```
$v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'Category' => 'required|max:100|min:5|unique:tblcategory,Category,'.$request->input('CategoryID').',CategoryID';
]);
```

It is also documented on [laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-unique)

Answer (score 1):

```
$v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'Category' => 'required|max:100|min:5|unique:tblCategory,Category,'
                         . $request->input('CategoryID'). ",CategoryID"
        ]);
```